# ModelForm doesn´t validate

Tags: django, django-forms

I just cant make my modelform to validate. I call it from view, and GET prints it right, but when POST occurs it doesn´t validate.
Allways getting

> ValueError Exception Value:    The view
> gestionPartesMedicos.views.partes_medicos_add didn't return an
> HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

form´s name attributes correspond to model´s and form´s.

---UPDATED---

This my model:

```
class MedicalList(models.Model):
    worker= models.ForeignKey(worker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    upload=models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, null=False, blank=False)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

this my form class:

```
class MedicalListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
worker = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Worker.objects.none(),
    empty_label=None,
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
description=forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
upload=forms.FileField(
    widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)

class Meta:
    model = MedicalList
    fields = ( 
        'worker',
        'description',
        'upload',
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['worker'].queryset = Worker.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
```

And this my view in trouble:

```
def medical_list_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MedicalListForm(request.POST,request.FILES,user_id=request.user)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('medical_list')
    else:
        form = MedicalListForm(user_id=request.user)
        return render(request, 'medical_list_add.html', {'form': form})
```

The form in template:

```
<form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">                
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    <a class="nav-item linking" href = "{% url 'medical_list' %}">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

this is the response I get:

> Request information USER 12345
>
> GET No GET data
>
> POST Variable Value csrfmiddlewaretoken
> '2zG3amQlZlPsrytMtF91ZiJQDZ679E2Zgrx3YxcOPzcNj6dNCl101Lj0UV96STLY'
> worker     '14' description    'pm' upload     'medical.pdf'

Might it be around Model field created_at? just trying to guess, totally lost.
thanks in advance

Comment: What is `worker`? A `ForeignKey` to a `worker` object or to a `Trabajador` object?

Comment: Sorry i just translated it to english, but missed that, It´s a Foreign key to a worker object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your view does not return a HTTP response in case the form was invalid. You should unindent the `render(…)` call with:

```
def medical_list_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MedicalListForm(request.POST,request.FILES,user_id=request.user)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('medical_list')
    else:
        form = MedicalListForm(user_id=request.user)
    # ↓↓ both for GET and a failed POST
    return render(request, 'medical_list_add.html', {'form': form})
```

Furthermore the form fields are specified at class level. By constructing a form field in the `__init__` method, this will not use that

```
class MedicalListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    worker = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Trabajador.objects.none(),
        empty_label=None,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    description=forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    upload=forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalList
        fields = ( 
            'worker',
            'description',
            'upload',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['worker'].queryset = worker.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
```

If your form handles files, you should set the [**`enctype=…`** parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    …
</form>
```

Comment: I want to give POST and GET different rendering, so I try to put in my way. Yours work, but leaves me without context for GET or with it for POST; also different templates to load.

Comment: So maybe by constructing in __init__ is the reason of not validating? Still not validating

Comment: @VidalM.: it means that it will not have used `form-control` as class. Normally if you update the view, the HTML form should render the errors now, at least if you rendered it with `{{ form }}`, or you added the `.errors` of the form and its fields as is described in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: yes, It renders errores now, and It says update field is required. But I can't understand why i do logics to decide between methods if i have to mandatory put a returns outside that logics. Pardon my english and low programming knowledge

Comment: @VidalM.: is the file required or not? If you use a file, does the form works in that case?

Comment: It is not required specified, and no, it's not working if any file is used, It just complains

Comment: @VidalM.: see update, in that case you specify `blank=True`, `null=True`, and `required=False` in the form.

Comment: I´m afraid i missunderstood. Pardon my lang skills again.. I meant it was not specifically said its nullable=False, but it must go in with that field required, so i tried to put null=False, blank=False, but same results

Comment: @VidalM.: but is the filefield *optional* (a user can make a record *without* the `upload` file), or is it required?

Comment: @VidalM.: can you edit the question with the HTML of the form of the template?

Comment: @VidalM.: the `enctype` in the HTML form was not set. See update.